# Negative Lookahead not match suffix

Tags: regex

I have an expression that is matching something, but am trying to get this not to match if it's followed by the suffix: one or more spaces, three dashes, one or more spaces, one or more digits, a slash, and finally one or more digits.  Here is the expression:

```
(?<=(^|\s+))[A-Z]+[ ]+([0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,3})?)/([0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,3})?)(?!(\s+\-\-\-\s+[0-9]+/[0-9]+))
```

And here is the text:

```
January        10.5/13.5   ---     22/26     ---
```

It's matching January 10.5/13, but I don't want it to match anything.

Comment: Your negative lookahead goes only until here:   `(?<=(^|\s+))` So the other stuff will be matched. One suggestion would be the closing paren to put in the very end of this expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As lookarounds are supported, you can change the positive lookbehind at the start to a negative lookbehind asserting a whitespace boundary to the left `(?<!\S)`

You can use `.*` to it to scan the whole line, instead of starting with 1+ more whitespace chars `\s+`

The negative lookahead `(?!.*\s-{3}\s+[0-9]+/[0-9]` asserts that what is on the right is not the suffix.

You can omit the quantifier `+` after the last character class, as it does not matter if there are 1 or more digits following...as long as it is not a digit.

Note that in the current pattern, the decimal part is an optional capturing group 2. If you want that whole value in group 1, you can make it an [optional group](https://regex101.com/r/HXr4fu/1).

```
(?<!\S)[A-Z]+[ ]+([0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,3})?)/([0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,3})?)(?!.*\s-{3}\s+[0-9]+/[0-9])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4KW35y/1)

Comment: Thanks, I got a variation of this to work.  I can't remove the positive lookbehind b/c it's used for other formats, and hesitant to use .* since it could slow things down where I'm at.  If you know whether this could be a problem with a lookahead, please let me know.  Thank you.

Comment: You can keep the initial positive lookbehind if you want. https://regex101.com/r/3e3Ep7/1 If you don't use the `.*` the `\s+` that you currently use can not cross a non whitespace char so you will not know if the pattern occurs after that.

Comment: It actually worked putting it at the end, same way (changed .* to .+).  Thanks again

Comment: @Kevin You are totally right, I must be tired :-) I updated the answer. Glad that it works for you.